# Microsoft Dynamics crm api-Create contact under account

Tags: php, api, dynamics-crm

Trying to create contact in Microsoft Dynamics crm using api.

The request url is `https://alliedmodulartemp.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts`

While creating contact want to set the contact under account (i.e) want to set _parentcustomerid_value.

Tried using the following formats:

```
URL:https://alliedmodulartemp.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts(POST)
input:
{
  "firstname":"alrinmyjammy",
 "emailaddress1":"leonmyjamkutty@gmail.com",
 "_parentcustomerid_value@odata.bind": "/accounts(a5f68843-ec4b-ea11-a812-000d3a579ca8)"

 }
input:
{
  "firstname":"alrinmyjammy",
 "emailaddress1":"leonmyjamkutty@gmail.com",
 "parentcustomerid@odata.bind": "/accounts(a5f68843-ec4b-ea11-a812-000d3a579ca8)"

 }
```

But the error is,

> An error occurred while validating input parameters:
>   Microsoft.OData.ODataException: A property '_parentcustomerid_value'
>   which only has property annotations in the payload but no property
>   value is declared to be of type 'Edm.Guid'. In OData, only navigation
>   properties and named streams can be represented as properties without
>   values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your body should be like below. I just tested with one of my CRM instance and worked fine for me.
url is correct `https://alliedmodulartemp.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts`

```
{
    "firstname": "Test 2 Postman",
    "lastname": "Test 2 Postman",
    "parentcustomerid_account@odata.bind":"/accounts(22B474B7-4F44-E111-8C06-1CC1DEE8BACD)"
}
```